# How to trigger a new conversation from bot to a Skype user ? Not sure what to send in the id parameter for Skype channel

Tags: c#, json, azure-bot-service

Use case : We have our ticketing tool web app.Now whenever a new ticket is created,bot should send a message to the user's skypeId who created the ticket .I am not sure what to pass in the skype id property.

I tried using bot connector api https://skype.botframework.com/v3/conversations

```
json payload

{
    "bot": {
        "id": "botId",
        "name": "YashPA"
    },
    "channelId": "skype",
    "isGroup": false,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "name": "Nikhil"
        }
    ],
    "topicName": "News Alert"
}
```

In the above json i am not sure what to pass in the member array's id property.If I pass skypeid or emailid it gives below error response:

```
"error": {
        "code": "BadSyntax",
        "message": "Bad format of conversation ID"
    }
```

Expected output : should get a valid conversationid.

Also I want to know if the approach I have taken is correct or there is some better way to do this implementation

Comment: Just to make sure I've got the flow right User creates ticket -> ticket generates JSON -> JSON gets sent to bot -> Bot proactively messages user?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes yes your understanding is correct

Comment: will the user be interacting at all with the bot prior to the creation on the ticket? Or will the ticket be created using the bot?

Comment: Both of the scenarios can happen .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots, by design, cannot contact Skype users BEFORE the user initiates contact with the bot. Once a user has taken that step, channel account information is created, which will have the field you're looking for.

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/1957) is an older github issue (from 2017, so it's v3). It talks about getting the channelAccount information you need.

Once you have the channel account info, it's a matter of making the bot send a proactive message to the Skype user once a certain function (one about ticket creation) resolves.